# Why applying as.Date() on "general" formatted excel variables can't work?

Tags: r, excel, as.date

I was reading in a .csv file into R, where the .csv file was originally saved in Excel format.

While preparing for the .csv file, i did a copy and paste of the content on a new spreadsheet, and the `Date.Sold` variable was formatted as "general" in Excel.

I am curious as to why applying the command `as.Date()` on "general" formatted date values (from Excel) can't work in R? It gives me a series of NA values. If I had formatted the `Date.Sold` variable into "date" in Excel before reading into R, the `as.Date()` command works fine. Why is this so? Is there any way to read these "general" formatted variables into proper dates in R?

Some information about my variable and the command I used:

```
 Str(Date.Sold):  $ Date.Sold : Factor w/ 789 levels "-","40965.00",..: 461 463 456 17
```

Command that I used:

```
A$Date = as.Date(A$Date.Sold, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give the year of the origin of dates in Excel: "1899-12-30" so your function should look like `as.Date(date, origin = "1899-12-30")`.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think you might misunderstand the as.Date() function:
You always have to specify in which format the date you want to convert currently is.

For example, if your date in character representation looks like this "02/08/2014" then you need to convert it with format="%d/%m/%Y":

```
as.Date("02/08/2014",format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

If your date is in the general excel format, you need to use the origin argument. For example:

```
as.Date(30829, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

In your case, you might need to do a type conversion first, since you have factors:

```
as.Date(as.integer(as.character(30829)), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! :) I understand the as.Date () command better now, and how the arguments should be inputed in different scenarios.